# ignore package.json from Webpack build dependency

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

it seems any changes in package.json, will cause Webpack cache invalidates and re-resolve all build dependencies.
we want to use Webpack cache in CI for every release pipeline to decrease build time, but the problem is for every release the version field in package.json changes so Webpack cache will invalidate and it will be useless.

any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: It really is a good idea to do a fresh build in CI. These are not corners which should be cut.

Comment: thanks for your response, we are working on a massive project so its fresh build time takes a lot, and as we release our changes once or twice a day, we want to decrease build time as much as we can

Comment: That makes sense, but you have alternatives. Given the size of the project, you will be well served by splitting it up into multiple projects, each with distinct tsconfig.json and package.json files.